# Value selected option dropdownbox

Tags: javascript

I've got a dynamic dropdownbox:

```
function chgAantal(i,artNr,lengte){
    var aantal=document.getElementById("aantal_"+i).value;
    if(isNaN(aantal)){
        alert('Voer een geldig aantal in...');
        document.all["error_"+i].src="/images/fout.gif";
        ok=0;
    }
    else{
        location.href="addcart.asp?act=change&aantal="+aantal+"&artNr="+artNr+"&lengte="+lengte+"&bdr=<%=bdr%>";
    }
}
<select onchange='chgAantal(\""+i+"\",\""+artNr+"\",\""+lengte+"\")' name='aantal_"+i+"' value='"+aantal+"'/>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
<option value='6'>6</option>
<option value='7'>7</option>
<option value='8'>8</option>
<option value='9'>9</option>
</select>
```

When I change the value in (for example) 7, the value changes in the script. But I can't see the selected value, the value displaying is always 1. 
How can I display the selected value?

I hope you understand me!

Regards,

Fraak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be specifying the value in the Select tag as is determined by the selected option. Useful DOM properties for working with select Elements are:

```
selectedIndex: gets/sets the Id of the selected option.
value: returns the value of the selected option.
```

What you need to do here is change selectedIndex.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement

Answer (score 0):

code is perfect i think problem is with onchange check if the variables u have declared is proper

Comment: It's a shopping cart system. This function changes the quantity of the articles to order. The price changes wheb I selected another value. Only the quantity display is worng, not the selected quantity.